# For EFA, is the Scree Plot or the factanal command (in R) more reliable in reducing dimensionality?

Tags: r, statistics, factor-analysis

I'm practicing EFA with Westbrook and Oliver's data on emotional responses to   consumption from 1991.

```
> data
     X1    X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8  X9 X10
1  1.00    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
2  0.20  1.00   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
3  0.08  0.30 1.00   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
4  0.13 -0.30 0.37 1.00   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
5  0.27 -0.22 0.28 0.80 1.00   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
6  0.22 -0.23 0.39 0.84 0.85 1.00   NA   NA  NA  NA
7  0.22 -0.20 0.45 0.76 0.82 0.92 1.00   NA  NA  NA
8  0.33 -0.07 0.46 0.67 0.72 0.80 0.83 1.00  NA  NA
9  0.31 -0.08 0.40 0.55 0.60 0.67 0.77 0.76 1.0  NA
10 0.25 -0.21 0.48 0.74 0.68 0.78 0.78 0.70 0.7   1
```

This is my script so far:

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", fill=TRUE, col.names=1:no_col2)
corr <- xpnd( data[lower.tri(data, diag=T)] , no_col2)

corr.pc <- eigen(corr)

plot(corr.pc$values,type="o", pch=16)
abline(h=1,col="grey")
sum(corrB.pc$values>1)
```

Visually, it looks like the bend is at F3. However, according to Kaiser's Rule, we would only keep the first two factors, since their variances are greater than one. I checked the original study, and it appears that they settled on three factors.

But when I checked to see if three factors was sufficient with factanal(), the answer was that more than three factors were needed. Five, in fact, appear to be the minimum number of sufficient factors.

```
fa1<-factanal(covmat=corr, factors=3, n.obs=125, rotation="varimax")
fa1         

fa2<-factanal(covmat=corr, factors=5, n.obs=125, rotation="varimax")
fa2
```

When the different measures used to reduce dimensionality differ, is it just a personal preference as to which measure to use? Keeping the number of factors to three made sense to me because the fifth factor is just a less comprehensive rehash of some of the variables from the first factor.

What's your take?